# Call two controller method from a single comandbutton click

Tags: commandbutton, actionfunction

what is the best practice to call two controller method from a single commandbutton click. I have a requirement that on single buttonclick, page will navigate to first page and also call add new method.
currently commandbutton calls only one controller method AddMore

```
<apex:commandButton value="Add New" action="{!AddMore}" onclick="this.value = 'Adding...'" id="AddMoreButton"    />
```

Method 1 -

```
public void AddMore()
{
        //count = count+1;
        Abv_Core_KAM_Competitor_Sales__c  newRec=new Abv_Core_KAM_Competitor_Sales__c  (Abv_Core_KAM_Account__c =Acc_Id);
        if(records.size()>0)
        {
            records.add(0,newRec);}
        else
        {    
           records.add(newRec);}
    }
```

Method 2 -

```
    public boolean getprev()
    {
        if(index == 0)
        return true;
        else
        return false;
    }
```

that also need to be called from same commandbutton

Comment: why not call your `getPrev()` method in your `AddMore()` method itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest and legitimate way to do this is by calling getprev method at the end of AddMore

Something like this:

```
    public void AddMore()
{
    //count = count+1;
    Abv_Core_KAM_Competitor_Sales__c  newRec=new Abv_Core_KAM_Competitor_Sales__c  (Abv_Core_KAM_Account__c =Acc_Id);
    if(records.size()>0)
    {
        records.add(0,newRec);}
    else
    {    
       records.add(newRec);}
    }
    getprev(); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following two lines of code should definitely work in your case:

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!getprev}" name="methodInJavascript" >
<apex:commandButton value="Add New" action="{!AddMore}" onclick="methodInJavascript();"/>
```

Comment: tried the same but its not working

Comment: @user59759 it works for me .... can you please check if you are missing something. Do you get any specific errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

```
<apex:actionFunction name="executeClass1Method" action="{!Class1Method}"/>
<apex:commandButton onClick="executeClass1Method()" action="{!Class2Method}">
</apex:commandButton >
```

Dont forget to accept the answer if it works

Comment: I've tried this:`<apex:actionFunction name="n" action="{!beginning}"/>
     <apex:commandButton value="Add New"  onclick="n()" id="AddMoreButton" action="{!AddMore}"   />` but it only adds new row but doesnt navigates to 1st page

Comment: @user59759, How do you expect navigating somewhere if you don't have any navigation method/function?